# I can't delete a channel I created on Slack

Tags: slack

I followed the instructions for deleting a channel by clicking on the gear icon and going to Additional Options ... but I only get 2 options:

- Rename this channel
- Set the channel purpose

I want to delete it, and I thought I could since I'm the one who created it.

Does anyone know how I can delete it?

Comment: If the #general channel has been renamed, rename it back to #general, it cannot be deleted

Answer (score 4):

Per [the Slack documentation](https://get.slack.help/hc/en-us/articles/213185307-Delete-a-channel), only Workspace Owners and Workspace Admins can delete channels. You also need to have joined the channel before you can delete it.

If you aren't an owner or admin, you can't delete the channel, even if you created it.

Comment: I am admin and I still cannot delete or archive a channel